# PDFThumbnailView duplicates pages instead reorder

Tags: swift, macos, pdfkit

This is my code:

```
class PdfViewerVC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var thumbnailsView: PDFThumbnailView!
    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!
    
    let pdfDoc = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/minchiorre/Desktop/scan.pdf"))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.thumbnailsView.pdfView = self.pdfView
        self.pdfView.document = self.pdfDoc
    }
}
```

In my viewController I only have a `PDFThumbnailView` and a `PDFView` and PDF file is loaded. The problem is: when I drag and drop in the thumbnail view pages are duplicated instead reordered (if I drag page 1 on page 4 I will end having page 1 at first position and another page 1 in last position instead having in only on last).
Is this a bug from PDFKit?

Comment: I have same problem